# ASP.NET MVC authorization without connection to DB, in code only validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, backend

Every sample I found for authorization in the MVC model in ASP.NET framework required connection to DB. And looks like:

```
  public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnViewModel model, string returnUrl) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, string.Empty)) {
```

where Membership relate to corresponding DB, is there any way to authenticate user in the backend without connection to DB, in code only?

Thank you!

Comment: it depends on how your users are defined. where do you want to authenticate them with?

Comment: You can add/create a custom Membership provider that does what you want.

Comment: Yes, what you want to do is possible. You can authenticate your user against any store you would like, but if it's not a Microsoft default, you'll have to implement  custom Principal and Identity classes to use for the process. Check out https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/principal-and-identity-objects  or if a Principal doesn't suit your needs, you could check out https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-3.1 for more information about .NET core authentication/authorization (combination of these 2 might be a good approach)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code please! Criticize if something is wrong. Thank you!

```
public ActionResult LogOn() 
{
    GenericIdentity gi = new GenericIdentity("Bob", "Passport");
    HttpContext.User = new GenericPrincipal
    (
       gi,
       new[] { "managers", "executives" }
    );
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(User.Identity.Name, false);
    return View("Index");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to validate your users against some known record source.  This can be in memory, in a database, through another service, or using an external Identity Provider like Auth0.

If you just wanting to test with a few predefined static users, then in memory is probably your best approach.  You can create a custom membership provider to do this by inheriting from the existing membership objects and overriding the methods that load the data.

Here’s a great example of how this is accomplished.

https://www.spiria.com/en/blog/web-applications/how-create-your-own-membership-provider-instead-using-sqlmembershipprovider/